# Send is undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.find(i => i.name === 'User'))
        
    const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        
    welcomeEmbed.setColor('#5cf000')
    welcomeEmbed.setTitle('**' + member.user.username + '** Has joined! **' )
        
    member.guild.channels.cache.find(i => i.name === 'welcome').send(welcomeEmbed)
})
```

Send is undefined im not to sure what to do.

Comment: This should work usually

Comment: If there is no result of `member.guild.channels.cache.find(i => i.name ==='welcome')`, it seems that an undefined problem will occur.

Comment: Make sure you have enabled intents.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is in `member.guild.channels.cache.find(i => i.name === 'welcome')`, There are no channels named 'welcome'.
You may want to add a check:

```
const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(i => i.name === 'welcome');
if (channel) { 
    channel.send(welcomeEmbed);
}
```